# Can disable the GoogleMap to move to a marker when clicked?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

The following is my current GoogleMap Setup Code.
I now want the Map to stop panning to a clicked Marker (which I added in another segment). I believe the right term would be, that I want the autopan to be on (?)

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        buildClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
    } else {
        ErrorManager.displayError(TBCError.PermissionDenied, this);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**panning** is formally referred to as **control gestures**, it would make sense you'll either have to overwrite a listener or disable a control with a boolean, so take a peek at this link [android documentation reference for control gestures](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/controls).

zoom control `UiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(boolean)`

or scroll (pan) control `UiSettings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(boolean)`.

Google Markers have a default behavior depending on the boolean returned by OnMarkerClick(...), 
"
Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event **and** that we wish for the default behavior to occur (*which is for the camera to move such that the marker is centered* and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one). return false;"
[android documentation reference for google api marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker)

Comment: This is not what I am talking about. If the user taps on a marker placed on the map, the map automatically centers to that marker. I want to disable this automatic centering.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've added what I believe you're searching for in the initial response. OnMarkerClick(...) should do the trick.

Comment: Yes thank you! Returning true in OnMarkerClick(); lead to the exact behaviour I wanted!

Comment: But in this way, markers cannot be clickable?

Comment: @Nameless, nope, you will process all you want in the OnMarkerClick() method.